# Why so many connections established?

Tags: node.js, heroku, rabbitmq

I am writing a program to work with rabbitmq via amqp on heroku.

The part of my program have this code:

```
console.log( 'APP START' );

//Connect to db and start
global.controllers.db.opendb(dbsettings, function(error,db){
  if (!error){
    global.db = db;
    console.log( 'DB: connection to database established.' );

   var con = amqp.createConnection( { url: global.queue.producers.host } );
    con.on( 'ready', function() {
        console.log( 'mq: producers connection ready.' );
    });
  }
});
```

As I understood from documentation I should get only one message upon successful connection to queue service.

Is there any particular reason why my output have a lot of lines containing **mq: producers connection ready.** like [this](http://pastebin.com/GhtaABRn) then?

Answer (score 0):

The amqp-node library automatically reconnects either when the connection is lost or when an error occurs in your code. I can't see anything wrong with your code above, but if any exceptions are thrown in your rabbit-related code (also in other places, such as connecting and subscribing to queues) amqp-node will try to reestablish your connection - and keep getting the same exception and keep retrying.